# Apache Tiles 2.2.2 - propagating values

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="home" template="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title"       value="My App" />
        <put-attribute name="header"      value="/WEB-INF/views/common/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu"        value="/WEB-INF/views/common/nav.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer"      value="/WEB-INF/views/common/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

How do I propagate the title value (My App) to header.jsp? In header jsp, when I do:

```
<tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" />
```

nothing is printed. When I do the same in home.jsp, My App is printed. cascaded=true has not helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear where you tried putting that `cascade=true` (assuming it's a typo in your question: it should be "cascade", not "cascaded") but the following works as expected:

**tiles.xml:**

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="home" template="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title"   value="My App" cascade="true"/>
        <put-attribute name="header"  value="/WEB-INF/views/common/header.jsp" />
        (...)
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

**home.jsp:**

```
    Title: <tiles:insertAttribute name="title" /> <br/>
    Header: <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
```

**header.jsp:**

```
Title in header: <tiles:insertAttribute name="title" />
```

---

The output is:

```
Title: My App
Header: Title in header: My App
```

Comment: cascaded :P oh the extra 'd' messed up my evening. :D Good catch.